# Yii mdmsoft yii2-admin suddenly not working

Tags: php, yii

I have a site that has been running and which use mdsoft/yii2-admin for user access control.  It has been working for months.  I haven't made any changes in at least a week (probably longer).  Suddenly today, no one can log in.  You use the login page for the back-end and when you login it redirects you to the frontend without loggin you in.

Could anyone suggest what could be causing this,  how to troubleshoot this.

Looking over the log file I see

```
[error][yii\web\HttpException:403] exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' in /home/co/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php:158

2019-06-25 15:01:48 [....146][54][-][info][application] $_GET = [
    'r' => 'admin/user/login'
]
```

Comment: Are you using `yii2-authclient` for authentication?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question.  What do you need to see to answer it?
'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
        ],

Comment: Recently there was a bug fixed in `yii2-authclient` which had similar symptoms. Something related to Google OAuth changes.